# subscribe(new Observer<T>()) vs subscribe(new Subscriber<T>()

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

What is the difference between `subscribe(new Observer<T>())` and `subscribe(new Subscriber<T>()`?
Which one should I use in what context?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question you should dive into the code of both functions, [subscribe(new Observer())](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L7663)  and [subscribe(new Subscriber())](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L7771).

In short, version with Observer first checks if the passed parameter is sub type of Subscriber and if so calls the second version otherwise it simply wraps the passed observer in a Subscriber and calls the second version.

Given that the first method basically serves as a wrapper, unless you have any reason to use Observer over Subscriber, you should use the latter.

Comment: Also note about usage: subscribers cant be reused(once unsubscribed it cant observe again), while observers can. So if you want to use same object to observe results many times - use observer.

Comment: @marwinXXII Thanks, is reusability only difference?

Comment: @shekar Observer is a simple interface for observing results, while Subscriber is a class which implements logic of receiving results and also is observer.